# The Random Walker Printer

Tags: code-golf, random

Draw a program or function that will write to `STDOUT` `n` times (each for one step) a string that contains a dot `.` at the location of the walker. The program also needs to write a line every `s` seconds (or wait `s` seconds after each line).

A random walk is a mathematical formalization of a path that consists of a succession of random steps ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)), such that every new step will be the last step plus a new value, so any `t`step value is just the sum of all the random values before ir plus the initial value.

The program should take 2 inputs and will use only spaces `" "` and dots `"."` on the output. The start value of the walker will be `20` such that the output should be a dot after 19 spaces.

```
                  . #19 spaces then a dot
```

Every new step the value will be the last value of the walker plus one of these`[-2-1,0,1,2]`(20% chance each). After the new position is printed the program should wait `s` seconds and the go to the next step. If the step takes the walker outsite the range `1 to 40` it should be just ignored and the walker position stays the same. The number of spaces will always be a number from 0 to 39.

#### Example

```
#input
Mywalk(s = 0.1, n = 30)

#output
                     .
                    .
                      .
                        .
                          .
                           .
                            .
                          .
                         .
                          .
                           .
                            .
                           .
                          .
                           .
                           .
                         .
                         .
                          .
                            .
                           .
                          .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                         .
                          .
                         .
                          .
                          .
```

#### Considerations

- You may take the input as any reasonable format
- The shortest code wins
- It's okay if your program only accept the seconds as integers

Comment: I assume `n` is the number of steps?

Comment: Yeah, I've clarified that, thanks.

Comment: I think you should say that the range is `1 to 40`, because the number of spaces is always `position-1`.

Comment: @geokavel that seems better, fixed !

Comment: ***Draw** a program*??? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 39

```
J19VEK+.d0QW<.d0K)+*d=JhtS[Z39-+O5J2)\.
```

Takes `s` as the first line of input and `n` as the second. Works on the command line but not with the online interpreter. My first Pyth program ever! Golfing tips are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Pyth! The only golfing  tip I can see is that you can use `Q` and `E` for the two inputs instead fo `hQ` and `eQ`, if you newline separate the inputs.

Answer (score 13):

## Matlab, 112

The core idea is generating a list of possible next positions and then uniformly drawing one of them. If we are e.g. at position $l=1$ the possible steps would be `[-1,0,1,2,3]` Of course if we would chose `-1` that would be invalid and we would have to stay at the same position. Thats why we replace the *invalid* positions with the current position, `[1,0,1,2,3]`, and then randomly chose an element from this updated list.

The OP asked us tho *draw* the program, so here we go:

[image]

The transcription:

```
function c(n,s);
l=19;                             %initialize position
for k=1:n;                          
    disp([ones(1,l)*32,'.']);     %print the line
    z=(-2:2)+l;                   %get vector of possible next steps (for l=1 we get [-1,0,1,2,3])
    z(z<0)=l;                     %prune invalids: here we just replace the the invalid positions with the current position
    z(z>39)=l;                    %   this ensures the same behaivour as staying in the same spot when going outside of the range
    l=z(randi(5));                %draw random sample of those
    pause(s);
end
```

Comment: -1 uses MathJax in a non-MathJax environment  ;)

Comment: O.o You know, equations that are *not* written in latex are just not quite as trustable, they might even be not true! Better be on the safe side.

Comment: Drawn programs should be measured in volume of ink, rather than bytes...

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, <s>136</s> <s>128</s> <s>116</s> <s>106</s> <s>101</s> <s>90</s> 86

```
$p=19;map{say$"x$p.".";sleep $ARGV[0];$x=rand(5)+$p-2;$p=$x>0&&$x<40?$x:$p}1..$ARGV[1]
```

Requires the seconds to be an integer.

Run with `perl <filename> <second delay> <number of steps>`.

There may be more golfing potential here, although honestly, I'm surprised it got this far. (Come on, only 6 more bytes to beat the bash answer...)

**Changes**

- Saved 8 bytes by removing unneeded parentheses and spelling out ARGV (it's actually shorter that way)
- Saved 12 more bytes by removing `$s` and `$n` and just using the plain `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`
- Saved another 10 bytes when I realized I could use `$"` and didn't need to specifically define `$u` as `$undef`.
- Saved 5 more bytes by rearranging the ternary and how `$x` is used and by using `map` instead of `for`.
- Saved 11 bytes by no longer accepting the seconds as decimals (challenge spec says it's OK.)
- Saved another 5 bytes by using `say` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>124</s> 119 bytes

@janrn and @Steve Eckert: I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer but here's essentially your version shortened down. The task is to draw a program or a *function*, so by using `f(s,x)` you can save quite some bits, as well you can use `max(0,min(x,39))` to avoid an extra `if` clause. Got it down to:

```
import time,random as r
def f(s,x):
 n=19
 while x:print' '*n+'.';time.sleep(s);n=max(0,min(n+r.randint(-2,2),39));x-=1
```

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, 81

```bash
for((s=20;i++<$1;t=s,s+=RANDOM%5-2,s=s<0|s>39?t:s)){
printf %${s}s.\\n
sleep $2
}
```

Edit: *If the step takes the walker outsite the range 1 to 40 it should be just ignored and the walker position stays the same* handled correctly.

Input from command-line options.  E.g.:

```bash
$ ./randwalk.sh 5 0.5
                    .
                     .
                    .
                  .
                 .
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## Processing, <s>150</s> 147

```
void w(int n,int s){int x=20,i,y,c=0;for(;c<n;c++){x+=y=int(random(5)-2);if(x>40||x<0)x-=y;for(i=1;i<x;i++)print(" ");println(".");delay(s*1000);}}
```

Usage:

```
void setup() {
    w(10,1);
}
```

Note: `1000` can't be changed to `1e3` for type reasons.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7, <s>198</s> <s>162</s> <s>143</s> 133

```
import time,random as r;p=20;s=0;d=input();w=input()
while s<d:
 print' '*p+'.';s+=1;p=max(1,min(p+r.randint(-2,2),40));time.sleep(w)
```

When calling the script with `python script.py`, the first input is the amount of steps, second input the time between steps (accepts float or int). Any suggestions for improving?

**Edits**

- saved 36 bytes due to now using `print ' '*p+'.'`, thanks to @corsiKlause Ho Ho Ho
- down another 19 bytes by removing tab indents, replaced them with one space or `;` where possible
- 10 bytes less thanks to @Bruce_Forte idea with `p=max(1,min(p+r.randint(-2,2),40))` (I can't comment on your answer as well, but thanks; don't want to copy it completely)

Comment: In Python, can't you just go `' '*p` to repeat the string?

Comment: Actually yes, didn't know that. Editing now, thanks

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 84

```
def w(s,n)q=19;n.times{puts ' '*q+'.';sleep s;q+=rand(5)-2;q=[[q,0].max,39].min};end
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 140 Bytes

Note: This program requires the LuaSocket package.

```
require"socket"p=19 for i=1,arg[2]+0 do print((" "):rep(p)..".")p=p+math.random(-2,2)p=p<0 and 0 or p>39 and 39 or p socket.sleep(arg[1])end
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 92 bytes

```perl6
my (\n,\s)=@*ARGS;$/=19;for (-2..2).roll(n) {put ' 'x($/+=(40>$/+$_>=0??$_!!0)),'.';sleep s} # 92
```

```perl6
my (\n,\s)=@*ARGS;
$/=19;
for (-2..2).roll(n) {
  put ' 'x($/+=(40>$/+$_>=0??$_!!0)),'.';
  sleep s
}
```

Usage:

```perl6
$ perl6 -e 'my (\n,\s)=@*ARGS;$/=19;for (-2..2).roll(n) {put " "x($/+=(40>$/+$_>=0??$_!!0)),".",;sleep s}' 10 0.001
                  .
                .
               .
              .
               .
                .
               .
                .
                  .
                 .
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>122</s> 117 bytes

```
$RecursionLimit=∞;If[#2>0,Print[Indent[a=Min[#3+RandomInteger@{-2,2},39]~Max~0],"."];Pause@#;#0[#,#2-1,a]]&[##,19]&
```

Recursive anonymous function, takes input in the order specified. Could probably be golfed further.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 125 bytes

```js
(s,n)=>(t=setTimeout)(c=`console.log(" ".repeat(p)+".");p+=m=Math.random()*5|0;p-=p>41|p<2?m:2;--i&&t(c,d)`,d=s*1e3,p=19,i=n)
```

### Explanation

```js
(s,n)=>
  (t=setTimeout)(                     // set inital timeout
    c=`                               // c = code for timeout to execute
      console.log(" ".repeat(p)+"."); // print the current line
      p+=m=Math.random()*5|0;         // move walker 0 - 4 positions to the right
      p-=p>41|p<2?                    // if walker was moved out of bounds (2 - 41 instead
                                      //     of 0 - 39 because the random move of 0 - 4 to
                                      //     the right has not had the 2 subtracted yet)
        m:                            // undo the move
        2;                            // else subtract 2 to make the move -2 to 2
      --i&&t(c,d)                     // while we have steps remaining schedule next one
    `,
    d=s*1e3,                          // d = milliseconds to wait between steps
    p=19,                             // p = position of walker (0 indexed)
    i=n                               // i = steps remaining (needed to make n global)
  )
```

### Test

```js
console.log = s => result.textContent += s + "\n";
var solution = (s,n)=>(t=setTimeout)(c=`console.log(" ".repeat(p)+".");p+=m=Math.random()*5|0;p-=p>41|p<2?m:2;--i&&t(c,d)`,d=s*1e3,p=19,i=n)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="seconds" value="0.1" /><br />
<input type="number" id="steps" value="30" /><br />
<button onclick="solution(+seconds.value,+steps.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## k4, 61 characters

```
f:{y{-1((y:1|40&y+-2+*1?5)#" "),".";."\\sleep ",$x;y}[x]\20;}
```

sample run:

```
  f[.1]30
                      .
                    .
                    .
                   .
                   .
                  .
                  .
                   .
                   .
                     .
                    .
                  .
                  .
                    .
                   .
                   .
                 .
                .
               .
               .
              .
            .
          .
         .
         .
          .
            .
              .
              .
                .
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 154 bytes

```
import time
from random import*
w=int(input())
z=int(input())
g=19
c=6
s=" "
while c:
    c-=1
    s+=s
while z:
    z-=1
    if -1<g<40:
        print(s[:g]+'.')
    time.sleep(w)
    g+=randint(-2,2)
```

Generate a string of spaces greater than the maximum required length, then print that string ONLY up to the char at index 'g', then print a '.'. Finish by incrementing g by a random value in the range [-2:2], and repeat.

If anyone could help me golf down that horrific input block, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: To golf the input, why not use `sys.argv`?

Comment: Also, instead of `while z:`, why not use `for i in range(1,z)`?

Comment: I'm curious, how did you get that this is 154 bytes? http://bytesizematters.com/ gives a different count (even if you disable counting whitespace)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI: Hmm...by the time I add in the initial call to `sys.argv` and the import, I can't see how I can save any bytes doing that. And even with the extra lines to declare `c` then decrement `c` and `z`, it's still cheaper to do it this way, by my count.

Comment: @p1xel: I counted whitespaces internal to the line, just not leading or trailing whitespaces. Is there a different scoring standard that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @SteveEckert What exactly does `c` do?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI `c` is regulating length when I'm generating my string of spaces `s` that I'm outputting a substring of prior to the `.`. It could be pretty much anything that won't make the string longer than whatever python's max string length is, but I haven't yet figured out how to do that using existing variables without increasing byte count.

Comment: @SteveEckert I'm pretty sure most people also count newlines: this is why you see golfed solutions compressed onto one line. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Whitespace counts, just an any other character. Assuming those 4 leading spaces are actually tabs, your code appears to be 177 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

## C funtion, 114

```c
s=20,i,t;w(int n,float f){for(;i++<n;t=s,s+=rand()%5-2,s=s<0||s>39?t:s,usleep((int)(f*1e6)))printf("%*c.\n",s,0);}
```

Pretty much a direct translation of [my bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67080/11259).

#### Full test program:

```c
s=20,i,t;w(int n,float f){for(;i++<n;t=s,s+=rand()%5-2,s=s<0||s>39?t:s,usleep((int)(f*1e6)))printf("%*c.\n",s,0);}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  w(10, 0.2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 35 bytes

```apl
⍬⊣⎕{⎕←⌽⍵↑'.'⋄1⌈40⌊⍵+3-?5⊣⎕DL⍺}⍣⎕⊢20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@j3jWPuhY/6ptaDcSP2iY86tn7qHfro7aJ6nrqj7pbDB/1dJgYPOrpAgpqG@vam0IUu/g86t1V@6gXxH7UtcjIAGTY/zQuYwMuIwA)

A full program which takes n as first input and s as the second.

```apl
⍬⊣⎕{⎕←⌽⍵↑'.'⋄1⌈40⌊⍵+3-?5⊣⎕DL⍺}⍣⎕⊢20
   {                         }⍣⎕    do the following n times
  ⎕                                 with s as constant left argument ⍺
                                ⊢20 and 20 as right argument ⍵
       ⍵↑'.'                        take ⍵ characters from '.'   
      ⌽                             reverse to pad with spaces
    ⎕←                              and display it    
                         ⎕DL⍺       delay s seconds
                        ⊣           suppress it's return value with
                      ?5            a random number in 1-5
                    3-              subtract from 3 to get negative possibilities
                  ⍵+                add current ⍵ to it
               40⌊                  minimum of that and 40
             1⌈                     maximum of that and 1
⍬⊣                                  suppress the final return value.
```